# The revenge of the gifted amateur … be afraid, be very afraid …

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the word 'amateur' and how is the amateur compared with the professional in this article on computing.

http://www.emeraldinsight.com/journals.htm?articleid=1822283

> They are “punching above their weight” in their dealings with larger competitors who are less exposed to these new skills and more restricted in their structures.

I was trying to find something on the 'amateur tradition' but I did not find what I was looking for.  Although I did find an article in the Guardian that pointed out that many famous authors were 'part-timers'.

> **The woes of publishing make it easy to forget that Fielding, TS Eliot and others were part-timers**

http://www.guardian.co.uk/commentisfree/2009/may/02/jk-rowling-charles-dickens-ts-elliot-books-writing

Comment: See (more than one of) Plato's dialogs. Timaeus is probably the first one you should look at, then Meno.

Comment: I saw this comment to one of my earlier questions:  Amateurs and beginners don't usually know the limits, so they imagine bigger, fail more frequently, and learn more often. – cornbread ninja 4 mins ago

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question related to the English language as much as a philosophical matter.

Comment: I find it difficult to be objective and rational about a question that I have written.  What sparked this question was a meta question: What is the role of non-experts on ELU? http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3054/what-is-the-role-of-non-experts-on-elu  I know that there are contributors who enjoy word play and I thought that this question would give them plenty of scope for their hobby.

Comment: @RobinMichael A good title states the question clearly and succinctly. Consider what exactly is the question you need answered and put that in your title.

Answer (score 1):

An *amateur* is an enthusiast, a lover of the thing. You can actually see that in the root of the word, *ama-* (love).¹ *Amateur* is often used in opposition to *professional* because amateurs frequently work for the love of something, rather than for pay. There is nothing about *amateur* which automatically implies less expertise than a professional (academic or otherwise) might be expected to have. In context it might have that connotation, or might not. These two senses of the word can be found in the [Oxford definition of the term](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/amateur):

> 1 a person who takes part in a sport or other activity for enjoyment, not as a job
>   *The tournament is open to both amateurs and professionals.*
>   2 (usually disapproving) a person who is not skilled

However the closely related [adjective *amateurish*](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/amateurish) does have that connotation.

> not done or made well or with skill
>   *Detectives described the burglary as “crude and amateurish.”*

### Notes

1. **amateur (n.)** 1784, "one who has a taste for (something)," from Fr. *amateur* "lover of," from L. *amatorem* (nom. *amator*) "lover," agent noun from *amatus*, pp. of *amare* "to love" (see **Amy**). Meaning "dabbler" (as opposed to professional) is from 1786. As an adjective, by 1838.
   —*[Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=amateur)*

Comment: I recently had it pointed out to me that the literal meaning of "amateur" is one who loves doing a thing, but that was because I was using it as an antonym for "highly skilled professional". I think that connotation is common.

Comment: @TecBrat I agree. That is reflected in the Oxford definition in the clause "*not as* a job" and in my characterization of it as "*rather than* for pay".